# The most efficient basket filling for a specific investment amount

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a topic related to creating an investment recommendation.
We have given a pre-imposed budget and X items with the following parameters: current_price, predicted_price, roi (return of investment). The purpose of the application is to create a shopping cart that will allow you to invest your money in the best possible way in order to gain the greatest possible net income.

The item's net earnings are calculated by:

```
predicted_price - current price
```

ROI of single item is calculated by:

```
ROI = (predicted_price - current_price) / current_price
```

Important for us is only a pure net profit and not exceeding the required budget. Therefore, there is no other division and you can create any combination of items, but you can only buy each item once (there is only single copy of each item).

General example:
We have $ 1000 to invest and a list of 40 different items. What combination of items to buy to spend $ 1000 to earn as much as possible.

I tried to approach the topic by collecting items sequentially, sorting descending by ROI until entire budget is used up. Unfortunately, there were budget gaps that were difficult for me to fill. I will show it on an another example:

```
Budget 1000$

name, current_price, predicted_price, roi
Item#1, 500, 750, 0.5
Item#2, 400, 524, 0.31
Item#3, 250, 325, 0.3
Item#4, 250, 325, 0.3
```

On my approach, the algorithm would recommend investing in the first and second items. The result will be incorrect because omitting the purchase of the second item would allow you to achieve a higher net income.
My investment (incorrect):

```
Item #1 i #2
Sum (predicted_price): 1274
Invested: 900              # out of 1000
Net: 1274 - 900 = 374
```

Correct result:

```
Item #1, #3, #4
Sum (predicted_price): 1400
Invested: 1000 
Net: 1400 - 1000 = 400
```

Question: will someone recommend any algorithm that will work for the above-mentioned problem?

Comment: So, the "value" of each item is `predicted_price - current_price`. Can items be split into arbitrarily fine parts? Are items limited? Should there be some minimum "diversification", i.e. not just buy the (seemingly) most valuable stock? We need more information. Seems like some sort of knapsack problem though.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for your answer. According to your tips, I corrected the description.

Comment: This is called a "knapsack problem" (more specifically, "0-1 knapsack problem"). "Weight" of your items are their current price, and their "value" is the associated net earning. You are trying to maximize the value with a limit on weight. You should be able to find lots of materials about this problem searching the term "knapsack problem". It is solved using dynamical programming.